# Pass a variable throughout a function

Tags: python, function, api, python-requests

I am fairly new to python. I am creating a project that interacts with an API utilizing the requests module. I am creating a number of functions based on the api requirements that uses the requests module in every single one. I want to avoid recreating the response variable in every single function that I create in this script. Is there a way I can establish the data variable to be passed in the sendit function so I can avoid putting the response variable in every single new function.

````
import requests
import json

def aws_polly():
    data = {
        "effects": {
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": "aws:polly",
                    "text": "This is a test",
                    "voiceId": "Matthew",
                    "volume": "5",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    sendit()


def sendit():
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:7472/api/v1/effects/", headers = {"content-type":"application/json"},data = json.dumps(data))
    if response.json() == {"status":"success"}:
        print("Successfully added points")
    else:
        print("Did not add points")```
````

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the problem in passing in the data variable to sendit, or that you don't want to create a `response` variable in each function?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I I didnt know how to pass the variable but I figured it now with sendit(data). Still learning here.